# How to add GitHub QGumboParser library to a Qt project on macOS?

Tags: git, macos, qt, homebrew

I want to use the QGumboParser (https://github.com/lagner/QGumboParser) in a Qt project on macOS. There is also an instruction about how to add it as a git submodule, but I am not really experienced to neither Qt nor GitHub yet - so I am really helpless...

So how can I use the library in my project? I can't just add it to a project because of another dependency in itself.

> Create Subdirs Project.
>
> Add application subproject. "Qt Console Application" for example
>
> Open project folder and create libs directory
>
> Run git submodule add git@github.com:lagner/QGumboParser.git libs/QGumboParser in terminal.
>
> Run git submodule update --init --recursive
>
> Add SUBDIRS += libs/QGumboParser/QGumboParser into the root project. QGumboParser have to appear in your project tree
>
> Right click to application project that need Html parser and hit Add library -> Internal library -> select QGumboParser in combobox. Click finish.

Answer (score 0):

I am immature in English. Please understand even if it is awkward.

I am a Windows user and have done this.(It is not a clean way) I hope this helps.

1. Download [gumbo-parser](https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser) And [QGumboParser](https://github.com/lagner/QGumboParser)
2. Paste all the files&folders in gumbo-parser into the QGumboParser/gumbo-parser folder.
3. Create a 'libs' folder in your project folder.
4. Insert the QGumboParser folder into the 'libs' folder.
5. Add it to your project .pro file.

> ```
> SOURCES += \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/attribute.c \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/char_ref.c \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/error.c \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/parser.c \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/string_buffer.c \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/string_piece.c \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/tag.c \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/tokenizer.c \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/utf8.c \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/util.c \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/vector.c \
>         libs/QGumboParser/qgumboattribute.cpp \
>         libs/QGumboParser/qgumbodocument.cpp \
>         libs/QGumboParser/qgumbonode.cpp \
>
> HEADERS += \
>         libs/QGumboParser/HtmlTag.h \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/attribute.h \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/char_ref.h \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/char_ref.rl \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/error.h \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/gumbo.h \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/insertion_mode.h \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/parser.h \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/string_buffer.h \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/string_piece.h \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/tag_enum.h \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/tag_gperf.h \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/tag_sizes.h \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/tag_strings.h \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/token_type.h \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/tokenizer.h \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/tokenizer_states.h \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/utf8.h \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/util.h \
>         libs/QGumboParser/gumbo-parser/src/vector.h \
>         libs/QGumboParser/qgumboattribute.h \
>         libs/QGumboParser/qgumbodocument.h \
>         libs/QGumboParser/qgumbonode.h \
>
> SUBDIRS += libs/QGumboParser/QGumboParser.pro \
> ```

6.Check that CONFIG is C ++ 11.